# Returning null from function that returns a reference

Tags: php, reference, return-value

If you have a function returning a reference to an object and it should return null if the object for some reason does not exist. What is the best way to do this?

If you just return `null`like normal you get a `Only variable references should be returned by reference`.

One way around is to do something like

```
$null = null;
return $null;
```

But that doesn't seem very nice. One way could of course be to throw an exception instead of returning `null`. But given we want to return `null` instead of throwing exceptions, is there a better/nicer way?

Comment: If you're returning an object, why would you need to return a reference in the first place? Objects don't get copied when they're assigned.

Comment: @Barmar raised a valid point. However, to stay on topic - if your function returns a reference to an *object* then have it do only that, which means the program flow is fine while the object you are pointing to exists. If the object doesn't exist for some reason, raise an exception. Now you have a function that will work as expected. However, seeing that we haven't got sufficient info to get to the root of the problem (you are solving something apparently), it's difficult to say what's elegant and what's not, or what the correct way would be.

Comment: If you still want to return a reference, the workaround in the question seems like the best solution.

Comment: I would use an if statement that returns the reference to the object if it exists, otherwise a hard coded return null.

Comment: @Barmar: I have run into a lot of different ways that objects are handled. They seem to be passed as references by default after some PHP 5.x version. Before that they seem to be passed by reference but are copied upon write so any change to the object causes you to end up with a "new" object and the changes are not reflected in the original object. This solved that for those versions. But information seems scarce and contradictory. From what version can I actually be sure that an object is passed as a reference throughout the system?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Arrays are copy-on-write, but I think objects have always been by reference.

Comment: It's kind of necessary for the whole object-oriented paradigm, if you're using a language without pointers.

Comment: @Barmar: Ahhhh ok... I think the time I noticed the issue it was actually in regards to an array of objects. So perhaps that array is what caused it. Or should the array elements still point to the same objects even if the array itself is copy-on-write?

Comment: Yes, I think they should, but maybe there was a bug in older PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this has been working pretty well for me

```
class Opinion 
{
    protected $presetValue = null;

    public function &getValue()
    {
        return $this->presetValue;
    }
}
```

I always make sure in reference functions that whatever i return is preset